# Merge into nested array of dictionary

Tags: ansible

I have something like this:

```yaml
vars:
    process_names:
        - name: myprocess
          exe:
            - /usr/myexe
        - name: myprocess1
          exe:
            - /usr/myexe1

    update1:
        - name: myprocess2
          exe:
            - /usr/myexe2
    
    update2:
        - name: myprocess1
          exe:
            - /opt/myexe1
```

Consider the `process_names` is the original data which I want to update in 2 different scenarios.

- **Scenario 1**: `update1` contains name as `myprocess2` and that entry is not available in `process_names`. Hence add that block. So the `process_names` should become:

```yaml
process_names:
    - name: myprocess
        exe:
        - /usr/myexe
    - name: myprocess1
        exe:
        - /usr/myexe1
    - name: myprocess2
        exe:
        - /usr/myexe2
```

- **Scenario 2**: `update2` contains name as `myprocess1` which is already available in `process_names`. Hence the existing block should be updated something like this:

```yaml
process_names:
    - name: myprocess
        exe:
        - /usr/myexe
    - name: myprocess1
        exe:
        - /opt/myexe1
    - name: myprocess2
        exe:
        - /usr/myexe2
```

I've achieved **Scenario 1** by a simple array concatenation `(+)`. However, struggling for **Scenario 2** where I have to perform update operation.

So far, I've tried with `combine` and `union`, but no luck. Ex: `{{ process_names | union(update2) }}`. Need guidance and help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This actually become much easier and the exact same operation for both scenario if your transform your initial list to a dictionary to apply the changes. The name becomes the unique key and you just have to combine with your update(s) (transformed to dict(s) as well). You can transform back to a list once done.

## Using only original data

The following example `process_update.yml` playbook:

```yaml
---
- name: update a process list
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    process_names:
      - name: myprocess
        exe:
          - /usr/myexe
      - name: myprocess1
        exe:
          - /usr/myexe1

    update1:
      - name: myprocess2
        exe:
          - /usr/myexe2

    update2:
      - name: myprocess1
        exe:
          - /opt/myexe1

  tasks:
    - name: Show original list for comparison
      debug:
        var: process_names

    - name: Apply updates to my list
      vars:
        process_dict: "{{ process_names | items2dict(key_name='name', value_name='exe') }}"
        apply_updates:
          - update1
          - update2
        my_dict_updates: "{{ apply_updates | map('extract', vars) | flatten | items2dict(key_name='name', value_name='exe')}}"
        updated_process_names: "{{ process_dict | combine(my_dict_updates) | dict2items(key_name='name', value_name='exe') }}"
      debug:
        var: updated_process_names
```

Gives:

```
$ ansible-playbook process_update.yml 

PLAY [update a process list] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Show original list for comparison] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "process_names": [
        {
            "exe": [
                "/usr/myexe"
            ],
            "name": "myprocess"
        },
        {
            "exe": [
                "/usr/myexe1"
            ],
            "name": "myprocess1"
        }
    ]
}

TASK [Apply updates to my list] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "updated_process_names": [
        {
            "exe": [
                "/usr/myexe"
            ],
            "name": "myprocess"
        },
        {
            "exe": [
                "/opt/myexe1"
            ],
            "name": "myprocess1"
        },
        {
            "exe": [
                "/usr/myexe2"
            ],
            "name": "myprocess2"
        }
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

---

## Going further

The above will only work if your list elements contain 2 keys (`name` and `exe`). If you add one or more keys to your elements, they will be lost during the list => dict transformation.

Below is an example to go around this problem. This is absolutely not bullet proof and the best solution IMO would be to transform your original structure to a dict from source.

The following `process_update_revised.yml` playbook

```yaml
---
- name: update a process list
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    process_names:
      - name: myprocess
        exe:
          - /usr/myexe
        a_key: some value
      - name: myprocess1
        exe:
          - /usr/myexe1
        a_key: other value

    update1:
      - name: myprocess2
        exe:
          - /usr/myexe2
        a_key: no value

    update2:
      - name: myprocess1
        exe:
          - /opt/myexe1
        a_key: changed value

  tasks:
    - name: Show original dict for comparison
      debug:
        var: process_names

    - name: Apply updates to my list
      vars:
        process_dict: "{{ process_names | groupby('name') | map('flatten') | items2dict(key_name=0, value_name=1) }}"
        apply_updates:
          - update1
          - update2
        my_dict_updates: "{{ apply_updates | map('extract', vars) | flatten | groupby('name') | map('flatten') | items2dict(key_name=0, value_name=1) }}"
        updated_process_names: "{{ process_dict | combine(my_dict_updates) | dict2items | map(attribute='value') }}"
      debug:
        var: updated_process_names
```

Gives:

```
$ ansible-playbook process_update_revised.yml 

PLAY [update a process list] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Show original dict for comparison] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "process_names": [
        {
            "a_key": "some value",
            "exe": [
                "/usr/myexe"
            ],
            "name": "myprocess"
        },
        {
            "a_key": "other value",
            "exe": [
                "/usr/myexe1"
            ],
            "name": "myprocess1"
        }
    ]
}

TASK [Apply updates to my list] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "updated_process_names": [
        {
            "a_key": "some value",
            "exe": [
                "/usr/myexe"
            ],
            "name": "myprocess"
        },
        {
            "a_key": "changed value",
            "exe": [
                "/opt/myexe1"
            ],
            "name": "myprocess1"
        },
        {
            "a_key": "no value",
            "exe": [
                "/usr/myexe2"
            ],
            "name": "myprocess2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the 2nd solution which covers another scenario I had in my mind

Comment: Please note that the best scenario is still to use a dict in first place since your names are unique. Usint `dict2items` <=> `items2dict` becomes much easier than the other way arround.